# C# form textfield values to be accessed by another function in other class

Tags: c#, database, forms, oop

I have to code in Object Oriented method. I have a form which is taking values from user, now i want to upload those values into the database, and the easier way would be if i code everything onto the *INSERT* button.

But i want it this way --> *ENTRY WINDOW*(My Form) opens and user enters/selects values for the *FORM*, Now when he presses *INSERT* the button should call my function *ADD_VALUES* in another class named as *DATA_MANIPULATION* now all the code should be in the *ADD_VALUES* function in *DATA_MANIPULATION* class and the values in the fields should be passed to the *ADD_VALUES*.

Please help

Comment: :can you show your code how you are doing this and where you are getting problem. so that anyone can help you on this.

Comment: i don't have the code written yet, i am not facing problem, I don't know how to code like this, one form gets value and passes to a function in another class which updates the Database

Comment: So you want us to write it for you?

Comment: no, i just want the idea how would i pass the textbox values to my function in another class, a basic structure

Comment: It's a basic concept but a complex one and not suited to this q&a forum.  Try typing c# tutorial into google, there are many great ones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am just giving you a brief description for your problem. Assume that Main function of program class is your click event of INSERT button on your form.

And there are two classes, one is simple POCO class(Modal) and other is DBWorker class.

I think this will give you some idea how to logic is going through this code.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {           
        //assume this main function is your insert button click event. Then

        Employee objEmployee = new Employee() { Address = txtAddress.Text, Age = Convert.ToInt32(txtAge.Text), Name = txtEmpName.Text, Salary = Convert.ToDouble(txtSal.Text) };
        DATA_MANIPULATION.ADD_VALUES(objEmployee);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

}

public class Employee
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public double Salary { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

public class DATA_MANIPULATION
{
    public static void ADD_VALUES(Employee objEmployee)
    {
        //code to insert data in the DB
    }
}
```